# Two swift functions increasing compiling time dramatically

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

After going back and reading my app's build logs, there seems to be a strange issue where two (relatively) simple functions are both increasing the compiling time by one minute each (58 & 53 seconds respectively). This can be seen in my build logs below:

[image]

These functions are in my CAAgeViewController and both reference a UISlider in my storyboard. They make sure that both the max and min sliders are at most within 1 year of each other, and either function sets a label to "18-24 Years" or something to that respect. They are as follows:

```
@IBAction func minAgeChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if round(minAgeSlider.value / 1) < round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1) - 1 {
        minAgeSlider.value = round(minAgeSlider.value / 1)
        ageLabel.text = String(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value / 1))) + "-" + String(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1))) + " Years"
    } else {
        minAgeSlider.value = round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1) - 1
        ageLabel.text = String(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value / 1))) + "-" + String(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1))) + " Years"

    }
}

@IBAction func maxAgeChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    if round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1) > round(minAgeSlider.value / 1) + 1 {
        maxAgeSlider.value = round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1)
        ageLabel.text = String(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value / 1))) + "-" + String(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1))) + " Years"
    } else {
        maxAgeSlider.value = round(minAgeSlider.value / 1) + 1
        ageLabel.text = String(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value / 1))) + "-" + String(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1))) + " Years"
    }
}
```

I am unsure what exactly is going wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no way that this is the cause of the slowdown, but why on earth are you doing the `round(slider.value / 1)` calls repeatedly? And while we're on the subject, what's the point of the `/ 1` in each of them? There's a lot of unnecessary stuff going on here.

Comment: You have the same complicated line of code copy and pasted 4 times. Why not create a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the chained-plus. (It's always chained-plus; ok, not *always* but always…)

```
ageLabel.text = String(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value / 1))) + "-" + String(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value / 1))) + " Years"
```

Replace this with:

```
ageLabel.text = "\(Int(round(minAgeSlider.value)))-\(Int(round(maxAgeSlider.value))) Years"
```

I'm fairly certain the `/1` isn't helping you here. `round` + `Int` should do everything you meant.

Comment: That was it- I'll definitely be weary of chained-pluses from now on! Thanks!

Comment: Do have a clue _why_ this is happening?

Comment: @shallowThought because resolving infix `+` operators is much more expensive than parsing along string interpolation segments

Comment: There are a lot of overloads on `+`. It is a combinatorially explosive problem to figure out the types you want everything to be and then figure out if any of the types you have might be coerced into any of those types. For example, `"-"` isn't a String. It's a string literal. You can use it to construct anything that is `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`. So Swift has to decide which of those things to construct, and then figure out if there's a `+` function that takes `String` and that other thing. When there are two `+` operators, there are a lot of possibilities to chase.

Comment: The `/ 1` probably was creating a headache, too. There are a lot of versions of `round` and `Int.init` and `/`, and `1` isn't "an Int," it's an integer literal, which can be used to construct a lot of things again. And every path you walk down means all the other types might shift and you have to consider those too until you finally find that one (seemingly, but not actually "obvious") solution. And finding one isn't enough. You have to prove it's the *only* solution or the expression is ambiguous. So "starting w/ the obvious" doesn't save any time.

Comment: @RobNapier `You have to prove it's the only solution or the expression is ambiguous. So "starting w/ the obvious" doesn't save any time.` I hadn't thought about that before, but that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @RobNapier Would explicit annotation with `as Type` save any time, by fixing some of the "choices" the type checker could have made? Or is proving that those fixed choices are acceptable take just as much time as type checking would take without them?

Comment: Sometimes, but in most cases no. In my experience, the places you can syntactically put a type annotation are not the places that have the most problems. For example, `Int()` above isn't a type annotation. It's just sugar for `Int.init()` and there are tons of those to consider. Swift doesn't have any syntax to say "this is precisely the function I mean." (That'd be a lot less useful than it sounds; how would you want to express "the method that this type gets via RangeReplaceableCollection where Element:Equatable"?)

Comment: The better solution usually is to break up complex expressions into simpler expressions and assign them to intermediate variables.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of the slowdown is the way that you're concatenating strings with `+`. For some reason that I haven't been able to figure out, it's *much* faster (at least in Swift 2/3) to append strings with `"\(string1) \(string2)"` than to use `string1 + string2`. Same goes for arrays and their `+` operator. We saw a 100x decrease in compile time when we changed how we're doing concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the division by 1 and casting your values to Double instead? They may already be Doubles, mind you. You may just need to call round().

Comment: I will give it a try